# How to replace an equal to sign in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, command, equals

I am trying to find and replace a string containing an equal to sign and I am not getting the intended result. But when the text does not contain the equal to sign, but only alphanumeric characters it works fine.

Code:

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchReplace - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchReplace.bat "SearchStr" "NewStr" File
::          SearchStr [in] - string to be searched
::          ReplaceStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Save the code above as a file BatchReplace.bat and create another file containing the search string.

Example tried:

Search string: abc=True

Replace string: abc=False

Expected output: abc=False

Actual output obtained: True=abc=False=True

syntax: BatchReplace.bat "SearchStr" "NewStr" File_name.txt

Can anyone please help me solve this issue. I am looking for a solution using only batch file commands and without any external application.
Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried escaping the symbol?

Comment: Hi, tried escaping as \= and ^=, but it didn't work.

Comment: [Sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) cannot work with `=` in the search string because this is used to separate search and replace string. However, you seem to intend to replace whole lines of text, so there is no need for such, you just could compare the line of text using `if "%%B"=="%~1"` and return `%~2` in case...